# how can I extract entries out of the HOSTS file with the command line tool in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, command-line, hosts-file, extract

It concerns the HOSTS file, Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. I want all entries/lines with a certain name in it to be written in a .txt file. how can I do this in  the command line tool?

Comment: Write a batch file to read each line and if it contains your criteria write it to your text file... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet.  I don't know what a batch file would look like in this case.

Comment: @BigChris That's not a very efficient way to solve a problem when it can be done in one line using a single built-in command ;)

Comment: Hardly fair lol... the OP didn't stipulate any preferred method or scripting language... and, as can be seen, some didn't know `findstr` existed, just like myself... a great solution by Lenniey, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could use findstr:

```
findstr "localhost" C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts > C:\localhost_hosts.txt
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know of this command.

Comment: great! thx. it worked.